# My answer was deleted by a mod and I have no way to contact them and make a case for undeletion. Is this normal?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-answers

I posted an answer on a stackexchange site, and it was deleted by a moderator. Admittedly, the analogy I used was a bit of a stretch and apparently people didn't understand it, so the deletion is understandable. I would be happy to edit the answer and make it clearer, but I don't want to spend time doing so if there's no way to undelete it. Apparently I'm completely unable to undelete the answer, and I'm also unable to contact the moderator to discuss the situation with them. I can't even add comments because "This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users."

Is it normal that an answer is deleted, the author is unable to do anything about it at all?

Comment: The way to contact Moderators is to post a question on the meta of the site where your question was deleted.

Comment: @ÄlËverett Ah, thank you! I didn't realize each site had its own meta. I thought this site was the meta site for the entire Stackexchange network.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a way to un-delete it if you've edited it to be clearer, just flag your deleted answer for moderator attention, select 'other' and explain that you've edited your answer and would like it restored.

The moderator will then review the answer, and if it's in much better shape, restore it. Just explain that you are actually trying to *answer* the question, not just comment on it.

If you think it can be salvaged and understand why it was deleted, you're probably right. Just edit it and flag.